# O certo é "Faz dois dias" ou "Fazem dois dias"?

Tags: verbos

Como saber quando usar o verbo "fazer" no plural ou no singular? Nas frases "Faz dois dias" e "Fazem dois dias", qual é o jeito correto de utilizar o verbo?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Em [duvidas.dicio.com.br](http://duvidas.dicio.com.br/faz-dois-dias-ou-fazem-dois-dias/):

> **Faz dois dias** é a forma **correta** de escrita desta expressão. A
> expressão fazem dois dias está errada.
>
> O verbo fazer tem sua origem na palavra em latim *facere* [...] e é um verbo irregular, podendo ser conjugado em todos os tempos e modos verbais, bem como em todas as pessoas gramaticais.
>
> Contudo, quando se refere a **tempo decorrido ou indica fenômeno atmosférico**, o verbo fazer se apresenta como verbo impessoal, sem sujeito, devendo ser **conjugado apenas na 3.ª pessoa do singular**. Verbos impessoais são também verbos defectivos, não apresentando conjugações completas.

Noto também que *faz dois dias* tem o mesmo significado que [*há dois dias*](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-ou-ha/7411), como também o [Dicas de Português](http://educacao.uol.com.br/dicas-portugues/ha-20-dias-a-20-dias.jhtm) refere:

> Quando se trata de tempo decorrido, usa-se a forma verbal, portanto "**Há 20 dias**, teve início a reforma do estádio", ou seja, "**Faz 20 dias** que a reforma do estádio teve início".